# How to do an average of a dynamic range in Excel? (VBA?)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list in Excel with basically two columns: `Date` and `Value`.

```
Col A     |Col B |Col C|Col D     |Col E
----------+------+-----+----------+-----
Date      |Value |     |Date-range|
2012/01/01|    10|     |2012/01/01| 8.33
2012/01/05|     5|     |2012/01/07|
2012/01/07|    10|     |          |
2012/01/13|     1|     |          |
```

I want to return the Average between two dates which I would set in two separate cells. Is that possible?

So let's say in Cell D1 I put "2012/01/01" and in Cell D2 I put "2012/01/07". It should return the average of the values in that date range, in this case (10+5+10)/3 = 8.33

I was able to return the cell (e.g. `C100`)  for both dates but I don't know how to include them in a range for an average. Or is there an even smarter way to do it?

Comment: Please insert a `code` block into your question and give some sample data. Are the dates listed in order in a single column, for example? What do you mean by "return the cell (C100) for both dates"?

Comment: Updated it accordingly.
By "return the cell (C100) for both dates" I mean that - in this case - have a formular (vlookup) to find the cells the set dates refer to - A1 and A3 - maybe it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have Excel 2007 you can use `AVERAGEIFS`. For your case

`=AVERAGEIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,">="&D1,A1:A10,"<="&D2)`

Where D1 is your minimum date, D2 your maximum date and A1:B10 contains your date and values ranges will return 8.33